# Is it possible to trigger an Ansible Tower playbook using Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, ansible-awx, grafana-alerts

This is more a question for gaining knowledge and choosing if we are heading to the correct solution.

I have my application being monitored through Grafana and Prometheus.
The self healing is currently being worked with by using Ansbile Tower. All the alerts based on application performance is managed through Grafana dashboard.

We know want to stitch both Grafana and Ansible playbook such that an alert in Grafana can trigger a playbook in Ansible.

I did not see any out of the box integration for the same but would like to know if there is a way i can use Grafana alerts to actually call a REST API or do anything around Grafana to call a playbook in Ansible.

Thank you,
Anish

Comment: Have you seen the [list of supported notifiers](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/old-alerting/notifications/#list-of-supported-notifiers) ?

Answer (score 0):

According the [Tower API Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html) **Jobs Templates** it is possible to launch Job Templates (Playbooks) via simple REST API calls like

```
curl --silent -u ${TOWER_USER}:${TOWER_PASSWORD} --request POST --location https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/${TemplateID}/
```

So it might be possible to use just a [Webhook](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/old-alerting/notifications/#webhook).